# Calculate the value closest to selected date range

Tags: powerbi, dax

to simplify my question, I have a table like this. The column Quantity represents the change of stock on given date and column Current stock represents the value I want to find.
[image]

and a standard calendar table - 'Calendar'[Dates] with unique dates.

I need an outcome like this:

[image]

The logic is that the formula has to find the nearest date lower or equal to the min and max range selection, so in this case dates 1.7.2022 and 19.8.2022.
There are obviously many other IDs and Warehouses involved as well as the **'StockTable'[Date]** has duplicate values.
The best I could do is something like this for the upper part of the range, but it does not work. Can you please help me?

```
Latest date stock = 
var selectedmaxdate = MAX('Calendar'[Dates])
return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(StockTable[Current stock]),
    'Calendar'[Dates] <= selectedmaxdate,
    LASTDATE('Calendar'[Dates])
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that it's a matrix/table visual and ID is a row value there.  Your measure was adjusted a little bit, please look.

```
Latest date stock = 
var selectedmaxdate = MAX('Calendar'[Dates])
return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(StockTable[Current stock]),
    KEEPFILTERS('Calendar'[Dates] <= selectedmaxdate)
)
```

Comment: I didn't test the measure, awating for your feedback.